# Are "factor" and "variable" synonymous in general usage?

Tags: meaning, differences

I was writing a personal insight essay and I wanted to interchange "x-factor" with "x-variable."

Current Quoted Usage:

> Our team is the X factor in your treatment."

Intended Usage:

> They almost hit the mark with their X variable marketing line.

Comment: Please give a reference to the conventional usage of x-factor

Comment: The sequence 'X factor' is really confusing me here. Can you actually fill that in with an example word that people might actually use?

Answer (score 2):

There are two questions here.

First, factor and variable are often used interchangeably, but they are not synonymous. From Merriam-Webster, [factor](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/factor) can be defined as "one that actively contributes to the production of a result," and [variable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/variable) as "an element, feature, or factor that is liable to vary or change."

Factor necessarily implies a statement of causality/relationship between X and Y, which is not necessarily the case for variable.

Second, the phrases "x-factor" and "x-variable" are not interchangeable in the context you provide. [X-factor](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/X%20factor) is defined as "a circumstance, quality, or person that has a strong but unpredictable influence."

It is generally used in a positive sense. [For instance](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/x-factor), "He's a singer who has the X factor."

In your example, the team has the X factor, which is a selling point/positive attribute. I am not familiar with "x-variable" as a term at all, and certainly not as one interchangeable with "x-factor" in that sense.

Comment: The answer is helpfully analytical but needs a reference (as does the question!) to allow us to see the conventional usage of x-factor.

Comment: While it is true that, according to the quoted dictionary definition,  a variable needn't be related to anything, it is, in practice always used in the contexts that involve a possible relation to something else. Moreover, a variable (in the sense that the OP has in mind) is, by definition, quantitative in nature, and it is expected (although that may, upon investigation turn out not to be so) that its relationships to other relevant quantities can be expressed mathematically; that need not be true of factors.

Comment: I would argue that the main feature of a "variable" is that it varies. For instance, the weather is variable, in that it varies. The main feature of a "factor" is that it impacts. For instance, the weather is a factor contributing to my willingness to go outside. Some variables are factors -- like the weather -- but not all factors are variable, since some are constant.

I also do not believe OP is necessarily using the term variable quantitatively. "Our team is the X-factor" implies a qualitative attribute which makes the team uniquely positioned to drive a desired outcome.

Comment: We do say that weather is variable (adjective), but we we don't normally say that weather is a variable (noun), unless that is an imprecise way of saying that, say, air temperature is a variable, and we normally say that air temperature is a variable only in the contexts of exploring how changes in temperature may be correlated to something else.